# My on demand revalidation api call takes too long that it gets timed out on Vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel

I made a kentcdodds inspired blog where I use Github as my CMS I store my blog content in the same repository as the code  in mdx format, I made a workflow that when something changes in that directory I send the names of the files changed to the server at "/api/revalidate" then I download them on the server from Github, compile them (since I use mdx) and store them in the database that's basically it.  problem is this whole operation takes too long and I end up with a "timeout exceeded 10s" on vercel
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. In my case, I pull a document from a Firestore collection, and build the page based on this document. Both locally (using a production build with next start), and with a free trial of the Pro-plan, it all works as it should. I can't see how this should take 10 seconds, and in fact, when I tried with the Pro plan, it took only about a second to execute.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to try out the steps provided by Vercel ([guide](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-lower-my-serverless-function-execution-time)), or you might want to try moving the project into a free 14-day trial of the Pro plan, to see if this works for you.

Comment: It's because I store some metadata as well as the code generated from the metadata to also a free plan database, which takes quite sometime.
I've been able to get around this problem by spinning off a dedicated express sever on heroku with my student credits to the heavy lifting for me and I only call nextjs to only really revalidate the page itself.